# I want to understand how client side performance (image , css loading time mainly)for one of the web application under 1000 concurrent load

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, lighthouse

I am planning to load the backend apis with 1000 concurrent users using jmeter and at the same time using chrome lighthouse or pagespeed insight tool to understand how the client side is performing.
Is this the right approach or is there any better way to do that ?

Tried to load the backend api with 1000 concurrent load and at the same time used lighthouse tool to check the client side performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Client side performance and backend performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend) are two different beat which are not very related.

If you're interested in images and style loading time - JMeter can give you that information, just configure it to [download embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

[image]

What JMeter cannot provide is i.e. JavaScript execution time, page rendering time, [web vitals](https://web.dev/vitals/) and so on, if you want to collect this information in an automated manner - JMeter can be integrated with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)